# Market share of android devices based on different hardware platforms

Tags: android, google-play, android-hardware

Is there a way to find information about market share of Android devices based on different hardware platforms? This question came to my mind as I was developing an application that did some complex processing, which could benefit from specific platform optimizations (e.g. SIMD instructions).

A large spread exists even among ARM devices, as there are ARM v5, v6, v7, v7 with Neon etc.

Google provides some information about [OS versions, screens & OpenGL](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html). Are there any data providers that share such data for the whole market (like App Annie or Google itself)?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways - Check them out and keep it going :)

Google :
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

INDEPENDENT SITES :

http://www.statista.com/statistics/271774/share-of-android-platforms-on-mobile-devices-with-android-os/

Enjoy !

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, I'm looking for information about *hardware platforms* (e.g.: ARMv5, ARMv7, x86, MIPS), not Android OS versions.